# I cannot create a new project in ionic 5

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying to create a new project with Ionic 5 but when I ran `ionic start client blank` on the terminal I got this error:

```
 npm.cmd i
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...latest","jake":"lates'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\De Stone Of David\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-07-03T00_18_32_357Z-debug.log
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess npm.

        npm.cmd i exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

My Ionic version is 5.2.1

What is causing this error and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: Check your package.json file for any edits. Also, it might help if you re run with --verbose and post output

Comment: which node version you are using?

Comment: the node version is v10.16.0